# Simple and quick to implement socket server in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a C# command line app (the server), that is executed by another app (the client). It simply does a command and shuts down. I'm trying to convert this "run and shut" method to a "constantly running" windows forms. I'll use sockets as a way for the client app to  talk to the server in C#. My client app can talk in sockets, but I need a quick and simple way to integrate socket server functionality in C#.

I've tried to work with the following, but they all seem overly complex to integrate. Do you have any idea how to use these effectively, or any simple socket server component in C#?

These seem quite robust, but complex:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/AsyncSocketServerandClien.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TCPIPChat.aspx?q=.net+socket+server
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketsByBobJanova.aspx

These seem quite promising (no idea how limited/functional they are):

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/xynetsocket.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SocketControl.aspx

Comment: This sounds like a problem that could be solved efficently with something like [0mq](http://zeromq.codeplex.com/documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for something which you can easily use to get your server and client to talk to one another check out [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net) and in particular the short example demonstrating the most basic functionality [here](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/952f51c14671/ExamplesConsole/BasicSend.cs), hopefully not overly complex!

Comment: The second link seems dead.  I tried creating a new BitBucket account, and the link says "permission denied."

Answer (score 4):

They may seem complex but the ASync Socket stuff isn't too bad and there are lots of examples on how to implement it.  Being Asynchronous makes it easy to handle multiple connections simultaneously so I'd recommend having another look at it.

I've not used it myself but the [TCPListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) Class looks simpler to implement and comes with some examples on it's use.

Comment: here's an example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dottys/SocketProgDTRP11222005023030AM/SocketProgDTRP.aspx